# Why the discrepancies between setting and music in "Moulin Rouge!"?

Tags: soundtrack, moulin-rouge

I've observed a few things while watching *Moulin Rouge!* that point to a rather old setting, e.g. the lamp beside Christian and also that Christian is using an old typewriter.

[image]
[image]

However, in the movie, I can hear modern music, e.g. the Indian song *Chamma Chamma* from the 1998 movie *China Gate* is used during the Evil Maharaja stage play.

I was confused with the timeline: an old lamp, an old typewriter, and a 1998 movie song.

In what year is the action of *Moulin Rouge!* taking place and what explains those contradictions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The action of [Moulin Rouge!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moulin_Rouge!) takes place in 1899:

> In the year 1900, a British writer suffering from depression named
>   Christian (Ewan McGregor) begins writing on his typewriter (...). He explains how one year earlier, he moved to the Montmartre district of Paris to become a writer among members of the area's Bohemian movement.

Regarding the usage of contemporary music:

> In the liner notes to the film's Special Edition DVD, Luhrmann writes
>   that "[the] whole stylistic premise has been to decode what the Moulin
>   Rouge was to the audiences of 1899 and express that same thrill and
>   excitement in a way to which contemporary movie-goers can relate."
>   With that in mind, the film takes well-known popular music, mostly
>   drawn from the MTV Generation, and anachronizes it into a tale set in
>   a turn-of-the-century Paris cabaret.

Comment: how people in 1899 take 1998 song then ?

Comment: @user40246 I'm not sure what do you mean. Could you elaborate on that?